# Consuming an ASP webservice with jQuery

Tags: web-services, jquery, mono

I found some other questions about this, but they didn't work for me :( So I'm posting my own question:

I've made an ASP.NET webservice in mono. The code for it is:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace testWebservice
{
    public class ws : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public ws() {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public String sendCar()
        {
            return "44.435006,26.102314";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call this webservice from a website using jQuery:

```
function getCar()
{
    $.ajax( {
    type:'POST',
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:8080/ws.asmx/sendCar',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(msg) {
      AjaxSucceeded(msg);  
    },  
    error: AjaxFailed
    })   
    function AjaxSucceeded(result) {   
              alert(result.d);   
          }  
    function AjaxFailed(result) {   
              alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);   
          }         
}
```

When I run the page I get an alert saying "0 error".
Cay anyone give me some advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the service to work you need to:

Add to your project a reference to `System.Web.Extension`.

Add a `using System.Web.Script.Services;` to your ws source.

Add:

```
[ScriptService]
```

to your ws class.

Add:

```
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

inside your web.config under the `<httpHandlers>` tag.

If you are calling `getCar()` from a button click add `return false;` after the method call so that the click will not cause a postback.

For example:

[image]

[Default.aspx]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="testWebservice.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>jQuery Web Service call from Mono using JSON</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCar()
        {
            $.ajax( {
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://127.0.0.1:8080/ws.asmx/sendCar',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(msg) {
              AjaxSucceeded(msg);  
            },  
            error: AjaxFailed
            })   
            function AjaxSucceeded(result) {   
                      alert(result.d);   
                  }  
            function AjaxFailed(result) {   
                      alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);   
                  } 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnTest" Text="Call WebService" OnClientClick="getCar(); return false;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[ws.asmx.cs]

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace testWebservice
{
    [ScriptService]
    public class ws : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public ws() {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public String sendCar()
        {
            return "44.435006,26.102314";
        }
    }
}
```

[web.config]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
Web.config file for testWebservice.

The settings that can be used in this file are documented at 
http://www.mono-project.com/Config_system.web and 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx
-->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="10" traceMode="SortByTime" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    <pages>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `System.Web.Script.Services` is missing in my current mono runtime Mono 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Wed Jun 24 05:31:11 EDT 2015) (64-bit), is there a way to manually add it?

Comment: Find out part of which DLL the namespace is and reference that DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in the service ain't right.
You are at least missing the

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

attribute on your class `ws`.

At http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/8/asp.net/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-a-webservice-asmx-method I posted a sample that worked for me a couple of days ago.

Be aware, that changing the return type from String to something else, requires you to send real json objects.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I can see, you're using the old asp.net 2.0 style webservice. Why are you setting json as the type of data sent? I don't think this fit with those kind of web services

Comment: I am using mono, and i don't know about the style in witch the webservices should be. And i don't know about json either. This is all an adaptation  of what i found and read about on the internet.